# Can you pay someone else's income taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

Is it possible to pay someone else's federal income tax if you know how much they owe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

That would be a gift from you to them which may have tax implications of its own. They can theoretically refuse to accept the gift but the IRS is not going to give the money back.

Comment: What if I don't give the money to them, but send it directly to the IRS? Suppose my friend tells me "I owe the IRS $4,000; i have no idea how I'll pay it," and I mail the IRS a check for $4,000. Is it still a gift to my friend, even though they never actually received the money?

Comment: @Someone of course

Comment: You'll need to know their Social Security number to in order to properly fill out the form for making an income tax payment. A name and a dollar amount won't cut it.

Comment: @ohwilleke: No problem. We have the Equifax data breach.